# SQLAlchemy ORM Event hook for attribute persisted

Tags: python, events, orm, sqlalchemy

I am working on finding a way in SQLAlchemy events to call an external API upon an attribute gets updated and persisted into the database. Here is my context:

> An `User` model with an attribute named `birthday`. When an instance of `User` model gets updated and saved, I want to call to an external API to update this user's birthday accordingly.

I've tried [Attribute Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html?highlight=attribute_instrument#attribute-events), however, it generates too many hits and there is no way to guarantee that the `set`/`remove` attribute event would get persisted eventually (auto commit is set to False and transaction gets rolled back when errors occurred.)

[Session Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html?highlight=attribute_instrument#session-events) would not work either because it requires a Session/SessionFactory as a parameter and there are just so many places in the code based that sessions have been used.

I have been looking at all the possible [SQLAlchemy ORM event hooks](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html) in the official documentation but I couldn't find any one of them satisfy my requirement.

I wonder if anyone else has any insight into how to implement this kind of combination event trigger in SQLAlchemy. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by combining multiple events. The specific events you need to use depend on your particular application, but the basic idea is this:

1. [`InstanceEvents.load`] when an instance is loaded, note down the fact that it was loaded and not added to the session later (we only want to save the initial state if the instance was loaded)
2. [`AttributeEvents.set/append/remove`] when an attribute changes, note down the fact that it was changed, and, if necessary, what it was changed from (these first two steps are optional if you don't need the initial state)
3. [`SessionEvents.before_flush`] when a flush happens, note down which instances are actually being saved
4. [`SessionEvents.before_commit`] before a commit completes, note down the current state of the instance (because you may not have access to it anymore after the commit)
5. [`SessionEvents.after_commit`] after a commit completes, fire off the custom event handler and clear the instances that you saved

An interesting challenge is the ordering of the events. If you do a `session.commit()` without doing a `session.flush()`, you'll notice that the `before_commit` event fires before the `before_flush` event, which is different from the scenario where you do a `session.flush()` before `session.commit()`. The solution is to call `session.flush()` in your `before_commit` call to force the ordering. This is probably not 100% kosher, but it works for me in production.

Here's a (simple) diagram of the ordering of events:

```
begin
load
(save initial state)
set attribute
...
flush
set attribute
...
flush
...
(save modified state)
commit
(fire off "object saved and changed" event)
```

## Complete Example

```
from itertools import chain
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary, WeakSet
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, object_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    birthday = Column(String)


@event.listens_for(User.birthday, "set", active_history=True)
def _record_initial_state(target, value, old, initiator):
    session = object_session(target)
    if session is None:
        return
    if target not in session.info.get("loaded_instances", set()):
        return
    initial_state = session.info.setdefault("initial_state", WeakKeyDictionary())
    # this is where you save the entire object's state, not necessarily just the birthday attribute
    initial_state.setdefault(target, old)


@event.listens_for(User, "load")
def _record_loaded_instances_on_load(target, context):
    session = object_session(target)
    loaded_instances = session.info.setdefault("loaded_instances", WeakSet())
    loaded_instances.add(target)


@event.listens_for(Session, "before_flush")
def track_instances_before_flush(session, context, instances):
    modified_instances = session.info.setdefault("modified_instances", WeakSet())
    for obj in chain(session.new, session.dirty):
        if session.is_modified(obj) and isinstance(obj, User):
            modified_instances.add(obj)


@event.listens_for(Session, "before_commit")
def set_pending_changes_before_commit(session):
    session.flush()  # IMPORTANT
    initial_state = session.info.get("initial_state", {})
    modified_instances = session.info.get("modified_instances", set())
    del session.info["modified_instances"]
    pending_changes = session.info["pending_changes"] = []
    for obj in modified_instances:
        initial = initial_state.get(obj)
        current = obj.birthday
        pending_changes.append({
            "initial": initial,
            "current": current,
        })
        initial_state[obj] = current


@event.listens_for(Session, "after_commit")
def after_commit(session):
    pending_changes = session.info.get("pending_changes", {})
    del session.info["pending_changes"]
    for changes in pending_changes:
        print(changes)  # this is where you would fire your custom event

    loaded_instances = session.info["loaded_instances"] = WeakSet()
    for v in session.identity_map.values():
        if isinstance(v, User):
            loaded_instances.add(v)


def main():
    engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    session = Session(bind=engine)

    user = User(birthday="foo")
    session.add(user)
    user.birthday = "bar"
    session.flush()
    user.birthday = "baz"
    session.commit()  # prints: {"initial": None, "current": "baz"}
    user.birthday = "foobar"
    session.commit()  # prints: {"initial": "baz", "current": "foobar"}

    session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, it's a little complicated and not very ergonomic. It would be nicer if it were integrated into the ORM, but I also understand there may be reasons for not doing so.

Comment: thanks for this comprehensive answer! I am still trying to wrap my head around why we need to chain 3 types of SA event hooks in 5 steps.  Care to elaborate more in simpler ways? Also, for step 3-5 in your example, Session is referring to the same global session factory, does it matter to listen for the factory not a particular session instance? I am confused as to what correct the event target should be hooked to for Session events.

Comment: @Devy Put simply, they each give you a piece of the information that you need in order to know that a state change on an instance has been committed, and not rolled back, or the instance was transient to begin with, or a bunch of other ways an instance can trigger one of these events that you don't care about. The reason it's the `Session` and not an individual session is because you want this to fire for *any* session, right, and not an individual session. (Otherwise you'd need to set up listeners for every individual session you have.)

Comment: Yes I want to fire for *any* session not a particular session. But I am using the session like this: `session = SQLAlchemySessions().session` https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/107#issuecomment-66729786 so how do I target instead?

Comment: @Devy In your particular case you can attach to all `db.s_*` instances because those are `scoped_session`s; this will affect all sessions created by the `db.s_*` proxies. Alternatively you can attach to the global `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session` class, which will affect *all* sessions.